# What happens to tweet URL when screen name changes?

Tags: twitter

Twitter's [published](https://support.twitter.com/articles/80586-how-to-link-directly-to-an-individual-tweet) mechanism for linking to tweets is to use "http://twitter.com/{ScreenName}/statuses/{Id}" -- where ScreenName is the user's screen name and Id is the unique Id for the tweet. But Twitter also allows users to change their screen name, and would probably allow two different users to have the same screen name if they are sufficiently distanced in time.

Given this, what happens to the tweet URL? Can it not be considered permanent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have noticed something that may provide the answer. You can actually substitute any string at all for {ScreenName} and the url still works (it will redirect to a url with the correct screen name). So it would seem that the only bit that really matters is the {id} - which obviously will be permanent, and from that Twitter will work out what the screen name is and redirect to get the right looking url - even if the {ScreenName} has changed